# Casting between different datatypes in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, int, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

Working on casting between different datatypes in C++... The program here below prints:

```
>"Number is 2"
>"Number is 2.5"
>"Number is 2"
```

Please, explain why the last printout is not "Number is 2.5" which I would expect after the C++ style cast to float?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int iNumber = 5;
    float fNumber;

    // No casting - C++ implicitly converts the result into an int and saves into a float
    // which is a conversion from 'int' to 'float' with possible loss of data
    fNumber = iNumber / 2;
    cout << "Number is " << fNumber << endl;

    // C-style casting not recommended as not type safe
    fNumber = (float) iNumber / 2;
    cout << "Number is " << fNumber << endl;

    // C++ style casting using datatype constructors to make the casting safe
    fNumber = static_cast<float>(iNumber / 2);
    cout << "Number is " << fNumber << endl;

   _getch();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: (iNumber / 2) becomes 2, which is then converted to a float, so the value will be 2. Order of operations. In the one before that, you cast iNumber to a float before it's divided, which is why it outputs 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
fNumber = static_cast<float>(iNumber / 2);
```

is dividing an integer by an integer BEFORE the cast to a float. This results in the following steps:

1. Divide `int iNumber` by `int 2` --> results in an int of 2
2. Cast the result into a float --> results in a float of 2.

If you instead do:

```
fNumber = static_cast<float>(iNumber / 2.0);
```

Now the result of the division will be a floating type of 2.5 before the cast and you should get 2.5 as expected.

Thats all well and good, but then why does

```
fNumber = (float) iNumber / 2;
```

work? This is because you're casting `iNumber` to a float BEFORE the division operation, so here again, you're dividing a float by an int and the result will be a float of 2.5.

Answer (score -1):

`static_cast<float>(expression)` expects an expression in parentheses which parentheses will determine the order of the operations.

To effectively cast an int into a float without loss of data in the C++ style,  the third expression needs to be rewritten with the parentheses around `iNumber` alone as in  `fNumber = static_cast<float>(iNumber) / 2;` to eventually print "`Number is 2.5`":

- `iNumber` is cast to float,
- `2` is implicitly cast to `2.0` and
- `iNumber` is divided by `2.0`.

Notice that the parentheses defining the order of operations are around the datatype in C but around the variable in C++.